# Select all items of union but not the last one!

Tags: jquery

I have few texboxes, dropdown lists, etc.. They have their css classes. I want to select all elements of specific class(es) but NOT the last element from group of all classes.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="class1" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="class2" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="class2" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I want to select only TextBox1 and TextBox2, not TextBox3!

selector should be something like this

```
$("(.class1,.class1):not(:last)")
```

or something like

```
    $(".class1,.class1").filter(":not(:last)")
```

but of course none of it is working :)

any sugestions?
tnx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your second selector is incorrect.  You were on the right track, try this:

```
$(".class1, .class2").filter(":not(:last)");
```

Comment: WOW U ARE FAST!
To be honest I don't see any difference except for space between class1, and class2, but what's more interesting is that the code I posted is working :) Your is working too. Could be I had a typo, that I accidently corrected when I posted the question :)
I found another way myself. See below.
Tnx anyway :)

Comment: You did have a typo, the second selector.  That is what my answer said.  You were doing the right thing, but you were selecting the same class twice.

Comment: oh I see, but my classes are not called that way in original code, and that was not the problem in the code. typo was on another place.
or it wasn't :) I don't know any more. Case solved! 
Tnx once again!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".class1,.class2").slice(0,-1)
```

Slice ftw! :)
I think it's faster, it just clips the last one, no filtering involved!